# Why Is The ID class i styled on my seperate .JS page not working

Tags: javascript, css, function, dom, styles

So this is what i did when i used the put the JavaScript on a separate page: Why is it not working?????(And i made sure the source page name is yellow.js and i just dont know how to seperate the javascript file on here)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="yellow.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="box" onload="change()">NBA Legends</h1>

</body>

</html>

function change() {
var box = document.getElementById("box");
boxStyle = box.style;

boxStyle.color = 'red';
}
```

Comment: it only works when I insert '<script src="yellow.js"></script>' underneath the <h1> id but why cant the text color be changed with the java script source only rendered in the <head> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function change()
{
 
 var box = document.getElementById("box");
 var boxStyle = box.style;

 boxStyle.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="yellow.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1 id="box" onload="change()">NBA Legends</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the difference between both

**window.onload** - it is called after all DOM, JS files, Images, Iframes, Extensions and others completely loaded. This is equal to $(window).load(function() {});

**onload**="" - It is called once DOM loaded. This is equal to $(document).ready(function() {});

It is always good to write clean code and I always prefer to use window.onload, instead of using onload event on element.

Comment: thank you a ton. and so in order for the function to be executed i from an external js page i have to use the window.onload event correct?

Comment: yes, You need to add an event listener for what you want.

Comment: @Agalar ahhhhh now im understanding....and so again just to clarify....the  'onload' event would only work if i put the script after the  <h1>

Comment: Great! Yes, correct. As it will only work when the page has been completely loaded. (Mentioned in my answer above as well.).

Comment: You can click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from gray out and you can also vote up the answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Ok yeah  i got it! @harsheet

Answer (score 0):

First put your javascript code into the body.If you want to change color when the page load you can use  `window.onload = change()` event. And your `boxStyle` variable is not defiend before you use it.I did some changes .

```
<body>
  <h1 id="box">NBA legends</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function change() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var boxStyle = box.style;
    boxStyle.color = 'red';
  }
 window.onload = change();
 </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: @AgalarTogrul....Right I understand that. So what i was saying is that in my actual text editor the JavaScript is in its own page, I only display it on here like that because I cant figure out how to write out two separate pieces without getting an error. So what your saying i already understand its just that its not working when i use an external unless i render it after the <h1>. Thats what im trying to understand because if its external why should i have to render it after the <h1> if its external, or is that the only way that it can be applied?

Comment: It no matters it's external or in the same page.Did you checked `src="yellow.js"`  is correct path or not ?