# not sure why .css() wont change div qualities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to change the value of the div 'dog' from blue (CSS) to red (javascript css code), but the javascript seems to not be functioning. CSS, JavaScript and jQuery are all linked properly (have checked).

HTML CODE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="dog"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
#dog {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (jQuery) CODE:

```
$("#dog").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: Timing is key. I'd guess that the DOM is not ready when your JS runs, so that there is no `#dog` in the document **at that moment**.

Comment: could you suggest any way to fix this? I added a few alerts before the jquery code to no result.

Comment: Your code itself has no problem. The problem is the sequence of loading the files, in your code, `script.js` is loaded before the html is loaded. You should therefore wrap your jquery code with `$(document).ready()` as others suggested so that it will only execute when the html is ready. Alternatively, move your `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>' right before the `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

> but the javascript seems to not be functioning. CSS, JavaScript and
>   jQuery are all linked properly (have checked).

Ensure that you encapsulate the javascript within a [**`$( document ).ready()`**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). This should solve the problem if the script is loaded in the `head` element, where the HTML document has not been loaded fully yet.

However, an alternative solution is to use the `script` tag within the `body` element.

**Example:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
     <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery
.min.js"></script>       
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
     <style>
      #dog {
         background-color: blue;
         height: 200px;
         width: 200px;
       }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="dog"></div>
     <script>
       $("#dog").css("background-color", "red");
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @j.hol if the solution has solved your problem, I would really appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: The `$(docment).ready()` in your code make no difference because the javascript is loaded after the html and css is loaded. It is only has effect if the script is loaded in the `<head>` where the html has not been loaded.

Comment: You don't need to do this if you put the JS at the bottom of the body. At this point, everything on top of the script has definitely been initialized.

Comment: I would argue that it is not necessary, but a good precaution so your code will work wherever the `<script>` element is placed, or moved to later (by someone else, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

do this in your js file -

```
window.onload = function () {
    $("#dog").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

The reason is this -

window.onload - it is called after all DOM, JS files, Images, Iframes, Extensions and others completely loaded. This is equal to `$(window).load(function() {});`

As you have a seperate js file, and you want the style to be changed when the page is loaded, so you have to do this.

For more understanding, you can refer this - [Difference between onload and window.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939078/why-is-the-id-class-i-styled-on-my-seperate-js-page-not-working/42939677#42939677)